# How can make a running example in LaTeX

Tags: counters, examples

I want a `continues example` where the same number is used for the example in different sections. Is it possible for LaTeX not to increase the counters for the examples?

Regards

minimum working code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{myexp}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexp}
This is the first part of our running example
\end{myexp}

.
.
.

\begin{myexp}
This is the second part of our running example
\end{myexp}


\end{document}
```

Comment: this isn't really clear.  an obvious possibility is to establish a set of counters that you don't use or change, then, before the examples where changes are made, reset the "working" counters to the values stored in the "invariable" counters.

Comment: `example` is not a standard latex command, so the answer depends on things you have not shown (every question should always include a complete example document). If you have defined example to increment a counter just modify the definition not to increment. If you have an existing definition you don't want to change use \addtocounter{example}{-1} to reset it

Comment: OK, I added a minimal working code. However, \addtocounter{example}{-1} solved the problem, it does not seem a maintainable solution. If I add another regular example between the parts of the running example, I have to manually manage the numbers. By the way, it seems the only working solution for the problem. Thanks

Comment: Just in case you have more than one `example` environment per section, you should execute `\setcounter{example}{0}` rather than `\addtocounter{example}{-1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Idea**

We use two environments here, the original `myexp` and another
one (actually based on `myexp`) `myexpcont` which signifies 
the continuation of the running example.

For the `myexpcont` environment, the theorem counter is kept unchanged
(by lower its value by 1 before start). We also add the text
*(continued)*  to indicate continuation.

**The Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{myexp}{Example}

\newenvironment{myexpcont}
{\addtocounter{myexp}{-1}\begin{myexp}{\textit{\textbf{{(continued)}}}}}
  {\end{myexp}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexp}
This is the first part of our running example.
\end{myexp}


\begin{myexpcont}
This is the second part of our running example.
\end{myexpcont}

\begin{myexp}
This is the first part of another example.
\end{myexp}

\begin{myexpcont}
This is the second part of our running example.
\end{myexpcont}

\begin{myexpcont}
This is the third part of our running example.
\end{myexpcont}

\begin{myexp}
This is the only part of another example.
\end{myexp}

\begin{myexp}
This is the only part of yet another example.
\end{myexp}

\end{document}
```

**The Output**

[image]

Comment: I think this will fail if the parts of the Examples are interleaved. Perhaps Example 2 starts before Example 1 continuations are finished. The OP hasn't made his wishes clear, but this might be one of them.

Comment: At least in my specific case it is not interleaved. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 9):

The `thmtools` package provides a direct mechanism for this, via a `continues` option.  You label the first instance with for example `\label{ex:first}`, and then in the subsequent instances provide the option `[continues=ex:first]`.

You can change the standard text printed by the `continues` option by redefining the `\thmcontinues` command.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{myexp}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{myexp}
  \label{ex:first}
  This is the first part of our running example.
\end{myexp}

Some text and interesting discussion.

\begin{myexp}[continues=ex:first]
  This is the second part of our running example.
\end{myexp}

More text and interesting discussion.

\renewcommand{\thmcontinues}[1]{continued}
\begin{myexp}[continues=ex:first]
  This is the third part of our running example.
\end{myexp}

\end{document}
```

The option to the `\thmcontiunes` is the label passed to `continues`.  The standard text generates the reference to the page of the first instance via a definition roughly equivalent to

```
\renewcommand{\thmcontiunes}[1]{continuing from p.\ \pageref{#1}}
```

(It actually contains more code that interacts with the `hyperref` package when loaded.)

Comment: What does "It actually contains more contain to interact..." mean? I think maybe there's a typo here but I don't know what it should say.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for asking.  It should now be fixed and hopefully clearer.